# Complex element validation in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation

Let's say I have a list of products and each product has 2 additional parameters from two list.

I.e. :

products: product1, product2, etc.

param1: val1a, val1b, etc.

param2: val2a, val2b, etc.

In my XML I need entries like:

```
<entry prod="product:element_from_param1:element_from_param1">
```

i.e.

```
<entry prod="product2:val1b:val2a">
```

Is it possible to validate something like this in XSD?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can encode your lists as a regular expression:

```
<xs:element name="entry">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="prod">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="(product1|product2):(val1a|val1b):(val2a|val2b)"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

However, if possible I suggest that you change your syntax and decompose the "prod" attribute into a proper XML structure (e.g., separate child elements or attributes).

For example:

```
<xs:element name="entry">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="product">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="product1"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="product2"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="val1">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="val1a"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="val1b"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="val2">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="val2a"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="val2b"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Unfortunately, I can't change the schema.